# Why do wireless routers claim speeds of 300 mbps but then ISP's only provide a fraction of that?

Tags: wireless-router, internet-speed

I am having quite a difficult time trying to understand internet speeds.  I have xfinity internet with a 50 mbps service, I also have a 300 mbps netgear router.  Why is there a massive difference there?  Even at xfinity best service of 105 mbps, it is still just a fraction of 300 mbps.  When I do an internet speed test I get about 10 mbps.  Yet, when googling this problem I came across people saying things like "Why can't I get more than 130 mbps".  This makes no sense to me, they are complaining about 130 mbps which is 25 more than xfinity best service and 120 more than the crap I get.  Please someone explain this in layman's terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 300 Mbps is the speed of the local wifi connection between devices and the router, and is independent of the WAN speed.

Comment: Oh, so if I were sending files from one computer to another locally it would transfer with 300 mbps? Also, do you think my internet speed of 10 mbps is too low?

Comment: It could *theoretically* transfer at 300 Mbps; there are more factors at work than just raw speed. It's impossible to tell if your speed is too low without knowing where you are; it's awesome if you're in a little country town in the middle of nowhere, but acceptable if you're in a suburb of SF, and mediocre if you're in Tokyo.

Comment: Okay cool I'm finally understanding it.  Thanks.